# google analytics chart installed app to web app

Tags: java, charts, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-java-client

Google Analytics has been installed in this part [Hello Analytics Reporting API v4; Java quickstart for installed applications](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-java)
of the Java environment.

However I want to show it as a chart on the web, is it possible to implement it directly with this object?

If so, what import statement is needed?

Answer (score 0):

Answer:  Neither the Google analytics API nor the Google APIs client library for java are designed for displaying charts on the web.

The Google analytics API is for retrieving data from Google Analytics.  The Google APIs Java client library helps you access said api.

If you want to display this data in a chart you will have to either making your own charting library for displaying the data returned, or find existing charting library for Java and alter the analytics response for use with said library.